# Responsive does not work when using DataTable in Modal with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, modal-dialog, responsive

I use DataTable with JS. Normally, when I use it inside the page, there is no problem in the responsive part. But when I add DataTable in any modal, the responsive feature does not appear.

How can I fix this?

My usage is as follows;

All codes are in "document ready"

```
$(document).ready(function(){           });
```

I open the modal in this way;

```
<button id="btn_TaskList" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal_TaskList"><i class="ti-view-list-alt"></i></button>
```

Modal Content this way;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_TaskList" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Task List</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn-close"aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="table-responsive overflow-hide">
                    <table id="table_TaskList" class="table display table-striped border">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Desc</th>
                                <th>Desc Res</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Created User</th>
                                <th>Updated User</th>
                                <th>Created Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

DataTable init like this;

```
$('#table_TaskList').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "searching":true,
    "paging":true,
    "info":true,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, -1], ['Default', 25, 50, 100, 500, "All"]],
    "sPaginationType": "simple"
});
```

This is how I fill data into the DataTable;

```
        $('#table_TaskList').DataTable().row.add([
            'Bla Bla Desc'
            ,'Bla Bla Desc Res'
            ,'Active'
            ,'Serdar Karaca'
            ,'John'
            ,'01-10-2023'
        ]).draw();
```

Comment: I tested it this way too, but it didn't work again. 
$('#table_TaskList').DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();